# Find all continuous functions $f$ such that $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ other than constant functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I could find that constant funtion $f(x)=m,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $m\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the requirement, but my teacher hinted that there might be more than just those, I need help on definding the other possible functions. Thank you in advance.